# Find the sides of this triangle (vector projection)

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

Given the situation as shown by the image and the data provided below, how do I find "11x" and "11y"?

[image: problem statement]

Known (estimated) values:

= 41.5276 degrees
p = 41.1603 mm
q = 185.6064 mm
r = 27.2885 mm

**Edit1**
The blue dotted lines are intended to be perpendicular.

Comment: There is not enough information for a unique answer. You could draw the blue dotted lines at different angles, and get different values for $x,y\,$.

Comment: @dxiv, I answered by editing the question.

Comment: Still not enough information. Draw a half-circle having $p$ as a diameter, and opposite $q$. Take any point on that half-circle and draw blue dotted lines to points $10$ and $11\,$, then those lines will be perpendicular. There still is nothing in the given information to determine *which* particular point on the half-circle is the "right" one.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance so far. I'm going to give up on this one because I don't see how I can get more information this way. No matter what, it's going to be an estimation so I will see if I can get the team to retake measurements instead of this form of a "guess."

Comment: You need one more angle in order for the figure to be solvable (or some length allowing the angle to be calculated). For example (assuming `11x` is horizontal), the slope of $p\,$, or of $q\,$, or perhaps the assumption that the line between $12$ and $11$ is vertical. Good luck.